# Laravel - href in ignored subfolder trouble

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, api-doc

I have a bit of trouble with  in a folder that laravel is ignoring.
In my .htacces I have a line that will ignore my folder called 'doc'.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(doc) - [L] <-- this one

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

and it works like it should.... kinda..  Example: 'localhost/doc/main.js' works fine if i type it direct into my webbrowser.

Here is my problem: in my /doc i have a 'index.html' that include/require/link some files into it from the doc dir. So in the index.html I have a line

```
<script data-main="./main.js" src="./vendor/require.min.js"></script>
```

When I go to 'localhost/doc' I get error that file cant be found (and alot others). linking to 'localhost/vendor/require.min.js'. This should be 'localhost/doc/vendor/require.min.js'

NOTE: this file is generated with ApiDocJS

Anyone have a solution for me, am stuck for about 4 hours now... am getting frustrated

---

Answer (score 1):

I'll suggest to try to do the same in a different way.

If you're stuck for so long on a problem like that, try changing the way you are following to accomplish your goal.

- Why that directory?
- Why ignoring it in `.htaccess`?
- Why not separate the logic of the app from the thing I want to hide?
- Can I configure the libraries I want to use in order to specify a directory?
- Can I refactor some of my code to prevent the ignore-the-dir-in-htaccess thing? (Since it's not common to do that)

That questions will move you to another direction that may or may not help you with your problem, but that's what I always do on a problem I'm stuck for more than 30 minutes, asking myself for another way of doing the same thing.

Comment: Q: Why not separate the logic of the app from the thing I want to hide?
A: Because one thing is laravel, the other part is something ApidocJs generates something from my laravel app, But I want both project in the same domain

Comment: Take in mind that all the laravel logic is outside the `public` folder. So Laravel hides the logic. But in JS that's different, because the logic happens on the client's browser, so the client MUST have access to the logic files.

Comment: @Niels Lucas do you use that Javascript library for doc generation? Check out Sami. Different way of doing the same.